# Le mot ‘voire’ peut-il modifier une proposition entière ?

Tags: grammaire

Si j'écris:

> Je m’inquiétais de ce que j’allais jouer puisque dans ce monde de
> rêve, je n’ai pas joué un instrument depuis deux ans, ou peut-être
> j’ai (voire?) même abandonné jouer de la musique entièrement.

Dans cette phrase ‘même’ modifie ‘j’ai même abandonné jouer de la musique entièrement’.  Mais il me semble que le mot ‘voire’ ne peut pas remplacer ‘même’ parce qu’il ne modifie que les noms.  C’est vrai ou pas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Voire* peut introduire une proposition entière, mais difficile de le montrer avec la phrase proposée dans la question.

En voici une réécriture montrant comment *voire* pourrait être employé :

> Je m’inquiétais de ce que j’allais jouer puisque dans ce (monde de) rêve, je n’**avais** pas joué **d**'un instrument depuis deux ans, [...]

> [1] ou peut-être avais-je même entièrement abandonné l'idée de jouer de la musique.

> [2] **voire** même avais-je totalement perdu toute vélléité de jouer de la musique.

Comment: J'allais corriger la concordances des temps, mais ta réponse le fait, et plus. Très bonne réponse.

Comment: Ma réécriture: _Je m'inquiétais de ce que j'allais jouer. Dans ce rêve, je n'avais pas joué d'un instrument depuis deux ans. Avais-je abandonné l'idée de jouer de la musique? Voire même toute volonté de jouer de la musique?_ mais je m'éloigne de l'original en utilisant plusieurs phrases courtes plutôt qu'une phrase qui devient un peu longue :-)

Comment: Puis-je dire 'voire' au lieu du 'voire même'

Comment: @bobsmith76 Oui, ça marche: _Avais-je abandonné l'idée de jouer de la musique? Voire toute volonté de jouer de la musique?_ mais ça sonne un peu mieux avec _même_. Aussi: _Avais-je abandonné l'idée, voire même la volonté, de jouer de la musique?_ pour "simplifier" - la répétition de _jouer de la musique_ n'est pas très heureuse.

Comment: Cool, merci beaucoup

Comment: 1/ On n'« abandonne  » pas la volonté, c'est une faculté (non idiomatique). 2a/ On n'abandonne pas non plus une velléité, mais on peut la perdre. 2b/ Il n'en était plus à des velléités puisqu'il jouait.

Comment: @LPH Bien sûr tout le monde peut avoir des opinions personnelles, mais il faut les exposer en tant que telles (à mon avis, je pense / j'estime que, etc...) https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/abandonner-volonte et https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/abandonner-velleite et on peut en trouver d'autres à l'aide d'un moteur de recherches. Dans la littérature religieuse abandonner sa volonté (à Dieu ou autre...) n'est pas rare. Par contre je ne trouve pas d'exemple de phrase avec « perdre » une velléité, mais c'est moi qui ai dû mal chercher...

Comment: L'expression habituelle est  "perdre *toute* velléité".

Comment: @Graffito Je prends. C'est encore plus courant en effet.

Comment: @None Il y a quand même une différence importante entre « abandonner » en tant que  « Renoncer à poursuivre une action, une recherche » (usage supposé) et « abandonner » en tant que « confier, remettre ou livrer à », et « volonté » n'est alors plus tout à fait la même chose mais « Disposition à agir conforme aux exigences du devoir et de la loi morale », ce qui n'a plus rien à voir avec « volonté » en tant que faculté qui permet de décider, par exemple, entre boire de l'eau ou du jus de fruit.